# Data is lost after changes are applied to the image

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am trying to add Elasticsearch to the EKS cluster. But whenever I apply the changes my data is lost. It looks like volume I have attached has been changed and reclaimed.

```
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-uat
  labels:
    component: elasticsearch-uat
spec:
  replicas: 1
  serviceName: elasticsearch-uat
  template: 
    metadata:
      ...
    spec:
      initContainers: 
      - name: init-sysctl
        ...
      containers:
      - name: es 
        securityContext:
          capabilities:
            add:
              - IPC_LOCK
        image: 559076975273.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/elasticsearch-s3:v2
        env:
        ...
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9200
          name: http
          protocol: TCP
        - containerPort: 9300
          name: transport
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts: 
        - mountPath: /data
          name: es-storage-uat
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      namespace: k8
      name: es-storage-uat
    spec:
      storageClassName: gp2
      accessModes: [ ReadWriteOnce ]
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 2Gi
```

This is a statefulset

Please help me to understand this concept. I do not want my data to loose in any condition.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: is it a Deployment or StatefulSet?

Comment: exactly. You are not saying what kind of object is this. Make it a `StatefulSet`, and it will work.

Comment: It is StatefulSet @PEkambaram

Comment: share output from kubectl get pv and kubectl get pvc

Comment: @PEkambaram screenshot attached to issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From pv output it is clear that PersistentVolume reclaim policy is set to Delete. Which means that if the pvc is deleted the PersistentVolume gets auto deleted. You loose the data if the pvc is deleted.

In your case, it is appropriate to use the “Retain” policy. With the “Retain” policy, if a user deletes a PersistentVolumeClaim, the corresponding PersistentVolume is not be deleted.

Further to the above, if you are using dynamic storage then set reclaimPolicy field of the storage class to appropriate value. If no reclaimPolicy is specified when a StorageClass object is created, it will default to Delete.

Comment: how I can do that for volumeClaimTemplates?

Comment: you are using gp2 storage class. set reclaimPolicy field of the storage class to “Retain"

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/#stable-storage. According to this "PersistentVolumes associated with the Pods’ PersistentVolume Claims are not deleted when the Pods, or StatefulSet are deleted." and I am using  volumeClaimTemplates

Comment: you are using dynamic storage using gp2 storage class. The reclaimPolicy field is set to default value 'Delete'. You need to set reclaimPolicy to 'Retain' to retain the data in case the pod/statefefulSet is deleted.

Comment: I added a storage class and now reclaim policy is retain.

```
$ kubectl get pv -A
NAME                                       CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                   STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
pvc-7a6bd65f-0133-11ea-bae9-0648541e65b6   2Gi        RWO            Retain           Bound    k8/es-storage-uat-elasticsearch-uat-0   standard                157m
```
Still if I change image version and apply change again the data is lost. Note that updateStrategy is RollingUpdate

Comment: is there any possibility that its storing data to pod's local storage?

Comment: you are storing data to external storage using gp2 storage class. it is not stored locally

Comment: one more thing, dont do rolling upgrade for statefulsets, it is recommended for deployments and stateless services